# named tuple for loop inline for many attributes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a named tuple with 30 entries and to make the code shorter, I'd like to do something like that:

```
from collections import namedtuple
header_dict = {0: "id",
               1: "PR_DISPLAY_NAME",
               2: "PR_HOME_ADDRESS_STREET",
               3: "PR_ZIP",
               ...
               29: "PR_SURNAME",
               }

Person = namedtuple('Person', '{} {} {}'.format(header_dict[0], header_dict[1], header_dict[2]))

s = '{} ' * 30
Person = namedtuple('Person', s.format(header_dict[(i for i in range(30)]))
```

The first "Person = ..." instruction works, but the second one results in:

```
KeyError: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fc2a1cff240>
```

I'm using Python 3.4.2

How should the code look like or is there an even better way to create this named tuple?

Comment: Usually namedtuples are for when you know the names of your fields and want a neat way to type them. The way you are using them feels like mixing data and variables. Why do you need a namedtuple and not e.g. a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use values

```
In [1]: header_dict = {0: "id",
   ...:                1: "PR_DISPLAY_NAME",
   ...:                2: "PR_HOME_ADDRESS_STREET",
   ...:                3: "PR_ZIP",
   ...:                29: "PR_SURNAME",
   ...:                }
   ...:                

In [2]: s = '{} ' * len(header_dict)

In [3]: s.format(*header_dict.values())
Out[3]: 'id PR_DISPLAY_NAME PR_HOME_ADDRESS_STREET PR_ZIP PR_SURNAME '
```

and your code will:

```
Person = namedtuple('Person',s.format(*header_dict.values()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can something like the following

```
Person = namedtuple('Person', s.format(*(header_dict[i] for i in range(30))))
```

From python 3.6, python dict retains insertion order. So from python 3.6, you can do

```
Person = namedtuple('Person', ' '.join(header_dict.values()))
```

Comment: But the order in 3.6 is not to be relied upon

Comment: True.. But from python 3.7 it can be relied upon and from 3.6 it works